# Restricting 0 or null value in am4charts LabelBullet in Column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using Column chart in am4charts , From ajax call I'm rendering the chart. 
I'm also adding LabelBullet to display the value of each bars in labels, but sometimes the result for a particular bar will be 0 or null. In that scenario I cannot able to handle the labels popping out for empty values.

I will post both the scenario, please help to restrict the 0 or null values.

**fiddle without adding labels :**

https://jsfiddle.net/Knavaneeth/89xz0yok/1/

```
var chart_data = [
    {vendor: "Amazon", price: 21.67},
    {vendor: "Cimandis", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Co-op", price: 0},
    {vendor: "easenmyne", price: 0},
    {vendor: "La Collette", price: 25.92},
    {vendor: "M&S", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Morrisons", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Tescos", price: 0},
    {vendor: "tesst", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Valley Foods", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Waitrose", price: 0}
];

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end  

var chart = am4core.create("amcharts_chart_price_compare_div", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data =  chart_data;

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());       
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "vendor";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;              

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 200;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;         

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "vendor";
series.dataFields.valueY = "price";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

**fiddle adding labels :**

https://jsfiddle.net/Knavaneeth/6eub51cz/1/

```
var chart_data = [
    {vendor: "Amazon", price: 21.67},
    {vendor: "Cimandis", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Co-op", price: 0},
    {vendor: "easenmyne", price: 0},
    {vendor: "La Collette", price: 25.92},
    {vendor: "M&S", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Morrisons", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Tescos", price: 0},
    {vendor: "tesst", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Valley Foods", price: 0},
    {vendor: "Waitrose", price: 0}
];

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end  

var chart = am4core.create("amcharts_chart_price_compare_div", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data =  chart_data;

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());       

categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "vendor";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;              

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 200;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;         

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "vendor";
series.dataFields.valueY = "price";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;

chart.series.each(series => {
    console.log(series);     
    var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
    labelBullet.setStateOnChildren = true;
    labelBullet.label.text = "{vendor}\n[bold font-size: 20]{price}[/]";                                     
    labelBullet.label.maxWidth = 75;
    labelBullet.label.wrap = true;
    labelBullet.label.truncate = false;
    labelBullet.label.textAlign = "middle";
    labelBullet.label.padding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#000");
    const background = new am4core.RoundedRectangle();
    background.cornerRadius(3, 3, 3, 3);
    labelBullet.label.background = background;
    labelBullet.label.background.fill = series.fill;
    labelBullet.label.background.fillOpacity = 0.9;
    labelBullet.label.background.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
    labelBullet.label.background.strokeOpacity = 1;
});
```

Finally I need a solution to display the labels in the chart only if has the values, 0 or other values should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Tooltip directly on the series and not only to the columns:

```
series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
```

After that you need to add a Cursor to your chart, which controls the Tooltips:

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

You can disable all the other axis tooltips, and cursor lines by using the following snippet:

```
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
categoryAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
```

At the end you may want to consider using the following to make the Tooltips show at the top of the column:

```
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywqLPX) is a code pen showing the final result.

To hide the LabelBullets for the zero values you can use an [Adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for the visible property:

```
labelBullet.label.adapter.add('visible', (visible, target) => {
    return target.dataItem.dataContext.price !== 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my requirement is I need to display the tooltips all the time without hovering  . 
Hope you understand and provide me a solution .

Comment: That was not part oft your question. But you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55019921/9662601).